# Laurent Series Expansion of $e^{(\frac{w}{2})(z-z^{-1})}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, binomial-theorem, laurent-series

I'm trying to expand the following in the region $|z|>0$
$$f(z)=e^{(\frac{w}{2})(z-z^{-1})}$$
to get its Laurent series expansion. If $a_n$ is the coefficient of the $n^{th}$ term in the expansion, I should be able to get,
$$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(w/2)^{n+2k}}{k!(n+k)!}$$
**My Approach so far:**
By Maclurin expansion we have,
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{wz}{2}-\frac{w}{2z}\right)^n\frac{1}{n!} $$ 
Now by Binomial theorem,
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\left(\frac{wz}{2}\right)^k\left(\frac{-w}{2z}\right)^{n-k}\frac{1}{n!} $$ 
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!k!}\left(\frac{w}{2}\right)^nz^{2k-n} $$ 
How can I proceed after this step? Or am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: Maybe want to introduce the new index $j := 2k -n$ since that'll expose the powers of $z$ explicitly.

Comment: How would you like to proceed? It seems like all that is left is a bit of simplification.

Comment: @Aruralreader Can someone show me how. I see it's just a matter of simplification but I'm stuck on this problem for a while now.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Properties) may help you.

Comment: @slhulk Somos’s idea gives a very simple sum and an answer right away for another series. [Here is the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p893W.jpg). Now maybe ask Somos to write an answer or not.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I don't think I'm required to apply this expansion directly. This problem was in an undergrad exam and this Bessel expansion wasn't even given as a hint. I should proceed as A rural reader said, but the process is very messy

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the product:

$$f(z)=e^{wz/2}e^{-wz^{-1}/2}=\\\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\left(\frac{w}2\right)^kz^k\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac1{j!}\left(-\frac w2\right)^j z^{-j}\right)$$

Combining:

$$\sum_{j,k} \frac{1}{k!j!}(-1)^j\left(\frac w2\right)^{j+k}z^{k-j}
$$

Letting $n=k-j,$ you get:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}z^n\sum_{k=\max(n,0)}^{\infty}\frac1{k!(k-n)!}(-1)^{k-n}\left(\frac w2\right)^{2k-n}$$

Everything converges absolutely here, so all these steps are allowed.

I don’t think you are going to get a closed formula for the coefficient of $z^n:$

$$a_n(w)=\sum_{k=\max(n,0)}^{\infty}\frac1{k!(k-n)!}(-1)^{k-n}\left(\frac w2\right)^{2k-n}$$
I can’t even find a closed form for the case $n=0.$ When $n=0,$

But it is an entire function in $w.$ It is odd when $n$ is odd and even when $n$ is even.

$$a_n(w)=\sum_{p=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{p}}{2^{n+2p}}\binom{n+2p}p \frac{w^{n+2p}}{(n+2p)!}$$

Since $f(z)f(z^{-1})=1,$ we get some conditions on the $a_n.$

When $n=-m<0,$ then:

$$a_n(w)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+k}}{2^{m+2k}}\binom{2m+k}{k}\frac{ w^{2k+m}}{(2k+m)!}$$

This shows that for $m\geq 0,$ $$a_{-m}(w)=(-1)^m a_{m}(w)=a_{m}(-w).$$

That’s because, if we write the function as $F(w,z),$ $F(w,z^{-1})=F(-w,z).$

Comment: Is there a way to combine all into just 1 sum instead of a double sum like by sum switching?

Comment: It doesn’t seem likely. because the $a_{n}(w)$ are infinite series in $w.$ You’d need a closed formula for $a_n(w).$ @TymaGaidash

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for the answer. I'll get back to this answer as soon as I'm free